# renderImage issue on shiny r

Tags: r, shiny

I have an issue about this code.

```
observeEvent(input$next, {
output$mark1 <- renderImage({
      return(NULL)
    }, deleteFile = FALSE)
})
```

This code is from the server file on shiny. And the UI file, the code is

```
imageOutput(
       outputId = 'mark1',
       inline = TRUE
     )
```

My expectation is, if I click 'next', then the image 'mark1' should disappear.

But I got an error message saying:

> Warning: Error in basename: a character vector argument expected

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO! Please provide a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) the next time - this will help to get help.

`renderImage` needs to return a list with at least a `src` slot. From the help of `renderImage`

> The expression `expr` must return a list containing the attributes for the `img` object on the client web page. For the image to display, properly, the list must have at least one entry, `src`, which is the path to the image file.

So you have to find a way how to tell `shiny` not to render the image *at all*  when your button is pressed. A neat way to do so is to use `req` like in the example below. The button `render` shows the pic and whenever you press `delete` it goes away. This is due to  the fact that `req` silently raises an error, which tells `shiny` not to proceed in the `observer/render*` function and thus not to show the picture in the first place.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(imageOutput("pic"), 
                actionButton("go", "Render Print"), 
                actionButton("delete", "Remove Pic"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   toggle_pic <- reactiveVal(FALSE)

   observeEvent(input$go, toggle_pic(TRUE), ignoreInit = TRUE)
   observeEvent(input$delete, toggle_pic(FALSE), ignoreInit = TRUE)

   output$pic <- renderImage({
      req(toggle_pic())
      outfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
      
      # Generate a png
      png(outfile, width=400, height=400)
      hist(rnorm(100))
      dev.off()
      
      # Return a list
      list(src = outfile,
           alt = "This is alternate text")
   }, deleteFile = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```